# Stop Firefox from displaying the "Prevent FireFox from displaying additional dialogs" message

Tags: firefox

I have a portal site for employees. At certain times, the script may display two alert messages in a row. When this occurs, FireFox offers the user the opportunity to prevent further dialogs from being created. When the user checks that box, none of the ensuing alerts will display during that session. This is not desired behavior in most cases.

If you have control over your user's browsers, as in the case of an internal program, see my answer below for how you can turn off that feature:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
1. Copy this string to your clipboard: dom.successive_dialog_time_limit
2. In FireFox Address bar Enter: about:config and press enter.
3. Accept the warning dialog.
4. In the preferences area right-click.
5. Select New-> Integer
6. Paste the string you copied previous and click OK
7. Enter the interger 0 in the next dialog box and click OK.
8. Close the about:config page.
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote on a perfectly legitimate post and for my using SO's ENCOURAGED use of the answer your own question feature.

Comment: This helped me. Got to love those cowardly drive-by down votes.

Comment: How to find what the default value is before overriding to 0?

Comment: The default should be 3.