# Trouble calling a javascript function inside $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){  
           $(":button").click(function(){
                alert("here");
                getDetails();
    });             
});
```

Inside the getDetails() function, I get form data and do a $.post to get some data. I originally had all of the code that is currently in getDetails directly in the .click() event and it worked that way, but I need that code to be called by a couple of different things, so I need the post not bound to a specific event. The page is getting to the click() function, because my alert shows up, but it isn't getting to the getDetails function. Any ideas? No console errors or warnings when I do the button click.

The code inside getDetails():

```
function getDetails(){
        alert("inside getDetails");
        var field1 = document.getElementById('field1').value;
        var oper1 = document.getElementById('oper1').value; 
        var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value; 
        var field2 = document.getElementById('field2').value; 
        var oper2 = document.getElementById('oper2').value; 
        var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
        var field3 = document.getElementById('field3').value; 
        var oper3 = document.getElementById('oper3').value;
        var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
        var rsCount = document.getElementById('resultSetCount');

        var formData = {"field1":field1, "oper1":oper1, "value1":value1, "field2":field2, "oper2":oper2, "value2":value2, "field3":field3, "oper3":oper3, "value3":value3, "rsCount":rsCount};
        $.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getInfo.jsp", formData, function(response){getXML(response)});
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your `getDetails()` function?

Comment: What does the body of `getDetails` look like? There's a good chance that it's simply an issue with the scope of `this` during the function call.

Comment: Are both sections of code included on the same page? There shouldn't be a problem http://jsfiddle.net/wc460tvt/

Comment: Are you sure that your selector should not say `$("button")`?

Comment: @Matthias is correct, `:button` is not a psuedo selector

Comment: Very likely a scoping problem.  Is the getDetails function defined in the global space?

Comment: @Matthias https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/ it's shorthand for `$( "button, input[type='button']" )`

Comment: can u paste ur html too?

Comment: @technophobia I agree, except that should actually cause an undefined error to appear

Comment: @JasonSperske right you are - sounds like we've got a little mystery on our hand :)

Comment: Yes. I have the function defined globally. Could it be a problem with the $.post not being in the document.ready function?

Comment: There's also the possibility that `getDetails` is getting clobbered by another chunk of code...more info required.

Comment: Could it be Firefox's "Prevent FireFox from displaying additional dialogs" feature? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872273/stop-firefox-from-displaying-the-prevent-firefox-from-displaying-additional-dia

Comment: @jordaniac89 maybe you should paste the relevant HTML?

Comment: I'm noticing their is some JSP code embedded in the `getDetails` function. Has this JavaScript function been moved to an external JavaScript file? If so, then the JSP tags inside the function will not be evaluated, and most likely a JavaScript error is being thrown when the browser issues a request to that URL.

Comment: Ok, guys. Don't hate me. Somewhere down the line, I had already defined a function: getDetails(){}, with just an empty function body. I deleted it and the code worked. Ugh... ALWAYS CHECK THE LITTLE THINGS FIRST.

Comment: I CALLED IT! :D Glad you were able to resolve your problem.